# how to retrive data from machine table processmaker 4

Tags: open-source, bpmn, processmaker

I have installed process maker 4.5.1 dockerised version from github. Is it possible to store the data in a separate database table? It stores in a machine table (pm4 ->process_requests), but how can I retrieve it and use for other purpose? I already wrote the script for that but it will not store the data which was filled by the user in the form task. Help me for this.

Thanks in advance.